# permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, pgadmin

I have an issue with the SQL Insert of binary data (small images in bytea) in my postgresql database.

My current Query:

```
INSERT INTO images(image_obj, meas_id)
    VALUES (pg_read_binary_file('C:\Users\LenaK\diverses\images\001.jpg')::bytea, 4);
```

However if I try to execute it the error message

> permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file

appears. I am currently the superuser.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unfortunetly that doesn't work...there seems to be an permission problem with pg_read_binary_file. I am executing it as superuser though (I already tried granting the function but it doesn't work either --> "ERROR:  function name "pg_read_binary_file" is not unique")

Comment: so you see, that;s y i said if you are sure of the permission, try GRANT xxxx TO your_role_name;

Comment: Contrary to your claim, you are not a superuser. Try `SELECT usesuper FROM pg_user WHERE usename = current_user;`, and you will get FALSE. Superusers *never* get "permission denied".

Comment: Alright thank you! I think I know what my problem is - I am using AWS and they supposingly don't give any user superuser privilages. Which means I can't grant or use this function to/with my own user...

Answer (score 2):

There are two sets of permissions you need to care about. The first are permissions inside the database (can you access the function or the images table, can you execute the function etc).

The second set are file permissions for the process reading the file. The server process which is executing your query almost certainly does not have permission to access your user directory. This is a good thing and should not be changed without thinking long and hard first.

Either move the files to import to some suitably publicly-accessible directories or change the ownership/permissions to match whatever your postgresql server is running as.